# Why the fileChannel.read loop never end?

Tags: java, nio, filechannel

I try to use nio to read a small text which contains only 5 characters,however, the fileChannel.read loop never go to end.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(Paths.get("input.txt"), StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        while (fileChannel.read(byteBuffer) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.flip();
            while (byteBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                char c = (char)byteBuffer.get();
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you forget to reset your buffer's limit and position after the inner `while` loop. After you read the first 1024 character, the buffer will be full, and each attempt to read into the buffer will try to read up to `remaining = limit - position` bytes, that is, 0 bytes once the buffer is full.

Also, you should always capture the return value from `fileChannel.read()`. In your case, it would tell you that it is continuously returning `0`.

Calling `byteBuffer.clear()` after the inner loop resolves the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(Paths.get("JPPFConfiguration.txt"), StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
  ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
  int n;
  long sum = 0L;
  while ((n = fileChannel.read(byteBuffer)) != -1) {
    sum += n;
    byteBuffer.flip();
    while (byteBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
      char c = (char) byteBuffer.get();
      System.out.print(c);
    }
    System.out.println("\n read " + n  + " bytes");
    byteBuffer.clear();
  }
  System.out.println("read " + sum + " bytes total");
}
```